Task.WhenAll is not waiting
I have below code, which should wait 10seconds. Problem is that it completes immediately, the WhenAll method is not working - what am I doing wrong here?
public class WhenAllIsNotWorking
{
    public async Task myFunc()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(new Task(async () => { await myFunc();  }));
        }
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.Start();
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

Edit, as I didn't mention this originally - above is oversimplified example of my real code - in reality I have a hierarchical tree of entities which I first traverse and register operations per entity (thus why I use new Task() with combination of task.Start()). Once I register all the operations, I then group them, and later do task.Start() on them which allow me to execute operations in ordered way per entity type. Of course that's what I would like to do, if it wasn't for the fact that WhenAll is not doing it's job here.
My solution, someone closed my question and I can't post answers anymore, anyhow, here is what I ended up doing - thanks for all your help!
public class WhenAllIsNotWorking
{
    public async Task myFunc()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }

    public async Task Init()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Func<Task>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(async () => { await myFunc();  });
        }
        var waitList = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            waitList.Add(Task.Run(task));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(waitList);
    }
}


Don't use async void

This did not solve the problem - even if Init is async Task it still completes immediately.

How are you calling Init()? It should be await Init();

@RaymondChen this code is only a quick example of my problem. I call it from a unit test class but in reality this is all async Task<T> which originates from somewhere in IHostEnvironment

When all is absolutely doing it's job. It's job is to wait until the tasks that are already queued up and mostly started have completed.

The Task constructor is not async-friendly (this is not the best link, but I couldn't find a better one right now).

@TheodorZoulias thank you for this link, I gave it a read and I have scaffolded something quickly after reading Stephen Cleary's answer. Code is not as tidy as I would like, but it's doing the job.

There is a difference in using task.Start() and Task.Run(). Task.Run() starts immediately, but task.Start() may not start immediately. Try using Task.Run() instead.

Not really a dupe, OP intent is different so that discussion won't answer the specific question

@ChrisSchaller the problem with the linked question is that it doesn't include a correct answer. Otherwise it seems to be a duplicate. I think that closing a question and linking it to a duplicate that lacks an answer is counterproductive, so I'll cast a reopen vote. I am pretty sure though that duplicate questions with correct answers do exist, but finding them is not trivial.

@ChrisSchaller Actually thanks to @TheodorZoulias' link I have sorted this out and updated my question to reflect my solution to this. I think I was using Task object incorrectly, now I used Func to store my operations for later, which also works. Thanks for all your help.

@ojek please don't include an answer inside the question. This is frowned upon here. I would suggest to remove the answer from the question, and post it as a proper answer.

@TheodorZoulias I wanted to! But this question is already closed and I can't add an answer anymore...

@ojek that is the correct assessment. A Func is an operation to execute later, where as a Task is a promise to complete a previously started (or scheduled) task. Tasks are used for asynchronous and parallel processing. While you can bend the pattern to create scheduled work, if you are doing this it is often considered an antipattern and there may be a far simpler and elegant solution to your needs.

@ChrisSchaller there is nothing complicated or inelegant to creating cold tasks and starting them at a later point. You might be influenced on this by the writings of Stephen Cleary. Stephen is 98% correct on everything he says, but his absolute rejection on constructing cold tasks is based on hardly any reasonable argument. He just doesn't like them. Exposing cold tasks from public APIs is a big no-no, but using them internally, especially in library code, is perfectly fine. Provided of course that you know what you are doing, and what better place than StackOverflow to share this knowledge?

@ojek my suggestion would be to remove the answer from the question anyway. Embedding answers to question is poor style, bends the rules of the site, and eventually acts as a tombstone that evaporates any chance that the question will ever be reopened. If you are determined to share your solution by all means possible, you could just include a link to the specific revision that includes the answer. Not very invasive, and it would keep your question in good shape.

Here is how to do it:
public async Task Init()
{
    List<Task<Task>> tasks = new();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(new Task<Task>(() => myFunc()));
    }

    // Do some operations in-between, before actually starting the tasks.

    foreach (Task<Task> taskTask in tasks)
    {
        taskTask.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    // Wait for all the tasks to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(t => t.Unwrap()));
}

Key points:

The non generic Task is not async-friendly. It doesn't know what to do with an async delegate. The delegate end-up being async void, which is something to avoid.
You can assign an async delegate to a Task<Task>. This is a nested task the represent the launching of the async operation. It doesn't represent the completion of the async operation. The outer task will complete immediately after the launching of the async operation. The inner task will complete when the async operation completes.
You can use the Unwrap method to create a new proxy Task that represent both the launching and the completion of the async operation.
Microsoft recommends to configure always the scheduler argument, whenever you start a Task with the StartNew and ContinueWith APIs. The same recommendation applies to the Start method. Otherwise your task will be scheduled on the ambient TaskScheduler.Current, which makes your code dependent on the ambient environment (not a good idea in general).


If you want to wait for tasks asynchronously, then you should not use await in any of the intermediary steps, the following simplification should work:
public class WhenAllIsNotWorking
{
    public async Task myFunc()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }

    // return Task, not void
    public async Task Init()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //tasks.Add(new Task(async () => { await myFunc();  }));
            tasks.Add(myFunc());
        }
        // Tasks should start immediately
        //foreach (var task in tasks)
        //{
        //    task.Start();
        //}
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

Update
If the issue is that you deliberately want to prevent the start of the task until after a certain point in time, then async/await was not specifically designed to solve this.
The better pattern for this is to have a queue of objects that have the concrete implementation or a reference to your action or delegate and then you can prepare your objects and only call a Start() method on the object when you are ready to execute it.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/V9J3Np
public class WhenAllIsNotWorking
{
    // return Task, not void
    public async Task Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Init()");
        var workers = new List<DoSomeWork>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            workers.Add(new DoSomeWork(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Workers Created...");
        
        foreach (var worker in workers)
        {
            worker.Prepare();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Workers Prepared...");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Tasks Started...");
        await Task.WhenAll(workers.Select(x => x.Start()));
        Console.WriteLine("Tasks Completed...");
    }
}

public class DoSomeWork
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public bool Prepared { get; private set; }
    
    public DoSomeWork(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;   
    }

    public void Prepare() { this.Prepared = true; }
    
    public async Task Start()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Completed Task: {0}", Id);
    }
}

Task.WhenAll() is absolutely doing what is expected here.
You could have also used a timer or cancellation token to delay the start of the workers, but conceptually the steps are the same.

When will my tasks actually start? I need to control the start time of these tasks.

At the moment of adding - method call starts the task.

I just tested your code - myFunc() starts immediately when added to the task list, thank you for this answer but it won't solve my use case, in which task.Start() is needed as I have to do some operations in-between before actually starting the tasks.

Make enumerable of the tasks - and feed it to Task.WhenAll, it would be a point of starting of all the tasks, internally in method implementation. Or enumerate them manually whenever you want.

Why not do those operations first? Your example was too simplified in that case. When you said "not working" you didn't mention that you were expecting a delay to start the work, that is not the problem that async/await is designed to solve.

@ChrisSchaller you are right, I didn't explain everything as I thought I made some simple mistake which I did not see. I have updated my question explaining why I need to split starting of the tasks.

Thank you for your edit! I ended up converting tasks.Add(new Task(...)) to tasks.Add(async () => { await myFunc() }) (with tasks being a List<Func<Task>> now). I then do Task.Run() on each element at a later time.
